# Python subprocess communicate hangs calling an external program, which ask for a keypress at the end

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to integrate [this](https://johndfenton.com/Steady-waves/Fourier.zip) executable in a python program. Basically the executable is a console application, it does some calculations based on input files, print some results on console and writes a couple of text files, then ask the user to press any key to exit.
Now, since I prefer to not re-building the executable I'd like to deal with the following issue. This is the code:

```
exe_path = 'Fourier/Fourier.exe'
cwd_path = 'Fourier'
process = Popen(exe_path, cwd=cwd_path, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = process.communicate(b"\r\n")
```

The problem is that the program is being run but it hangs on process.communicate. Removing last line everything works but the program remains running in the background, which is not fine for me. Any idea ?

Comment: if the output goes over certain byte limit - and you are *not* reading  pipe, process will hang on windows till you actually read the input..

Comment: Try running `echo. | Fourier/Fourier.exe` and adding `shell=True`. Or put that command in a batch file and execute the batch file.